# How to display a number in Pygame that is related to rectangle position?

Tags: python, text, fonts, numbers, pygame

I want to move rectangle on the screen let's say vertically and have attached to it a number dynamically changing and representing rect's position, is it even possible? Help greatly appreciated my whole project depends on that.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but please add more detail. Just what number "representing rect's position" do you want--the y-coordinate of its top, for example? How often will the rectangle be moved--is it so fast that the viewer will not be able to read the rapidly-changing number? Is there any limitation on the font--a fixed-width font would better handle rapidly-changing numbers, especially if any text changes as well. Finally, what other research have you done and what have you tried? Exactly where are you stuck--do you know how to display text on the pygame screen?

Comment: I know how to display text I have it attached to the top of my rectangle but as a font is a text object I cannot make the value change dynamically. I need pygame.mousemotion's rect.y position to display whenever I drag a rect with the mouse. I guess I must somehow convert returned y value to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rerender the text surface every time the position of the rect changes (for example if a `MOUSEMOTION` event occurs) and then blit it at the current rect position.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 32)
    font_color = (100, 200, 150)
    rect = pg.Rect(20, 200, 80, 50)
    txt_surf = font.render(str(rect.topleft), True, font_color)
    selected = None
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if selected:
                    selected = None
                elif rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected = rect
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                if selected:
                    selected.center = event.pos
                    txt_surf = font.render(str(rect.topleft), True, font_color)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pg.draw.rect(screen, font_color, rect, 2)
        screen.blit(txt_surf, (rect.right+10, rect.top))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Perfect answer as always, still trying to implement it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code that shows the position of the mouse cursor while the left mouse button is pressed. In this case the "number dynamically changing" is the mouse cursor position.

As you see in the code, I use a monospace font (Courier New in Windows) so any leading spaces in the numbers will not change the size of the numbers-- the number `12` with a space takes the same amount of screen real estate as does the number `199`. Each time through the main loop, about 60 times a second thanks to 
the `timer.tick(60)` statement, the string is built  from the desired numbers, then a surface called `text` is build from the string, then the surface is blitted to the screen.

Is it clear how to apply this to your situation?

```
"""A pygame "game" that shows the position of the mouse cursor while 
the left mouse button is pressed."""

import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
pygame.display.set_caption("Show the Position of the Mouse while Dragging")
BLACK= (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier New", 24)
mouse_is_down = False

keep_going = True
while keep_going:
    # Handle events.
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            keep_going = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:    # Left mouse button
                mouse_is_down = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if not pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:    # Left mouse button
                mouse_is_down = False

    # Draw the screen.
    screen.fill(BLACK)    
    if mouse_is_down:
        position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        position_string = 'Mouse position: ({:3d}, {:3d})'.format(*position)
    else:
        position_string = ''

    text = font.render(position_string, True, RED)
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.right = screen.get_rect().right - 10
    text_rect.y = 10
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    timer.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The other answer is more suitable for my problem, but thanks a lot anyway!